# Magento 2: Can't delete additional address from address book

Tags: customer-account, magento-2.1.7, address

When I am going to delete an address from "My Account" address book I am getting error message We can't delete the address right now.

But some other account I can delete the address.

I have checked controller file or delete the address and it's giving an error from the catch.

```
if ($addressId && $this->_formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
        try {
            $address = $this->_addressRepository->getById($addressId);
            if ($address->getCustomerId() === $this->_getSession()->getCustomerId()) {
                $this->_addressRepository->deleteById($addressId);
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('You deleted the address.'));
            } else {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('We can\'t delete the address right now.'));
            }
        } catch (\Exception $other) {
            $this->messageManager->addException($other, __('We can\'t delete the address right now.'));
        }
    }
```

Also in the system log, it's give an error like main.CRITICAL: Exception message: "Street Address" cannot contain more than 1 lines.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue. It was due to in admin side 1 address line set for the customer and  addresses which i was deleting were more than two lines.

So i have set default in backend after this deleted existing address and again set to 1 line. Now it's working.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a core magento issue

It checks the type of customerID from session and address object here
$address->getCustomerId() === $this->_getSession()->getCustomerId()

So the one from $address->getCustomerId() is int and $this->_getSession()->getCustomerId() seems string.

If you replace === with == , it will work as expected

Answer (score 1):

Update interface for Delete.php file
directory: vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Address/Delete.php

comment line no 9 to 11

```
/* use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface;

class Delete extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Address implements HttpPostActionInterface */
```

change code

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface as HttpGetActionInterface;

class Delete extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Address implements HttpGetActionInterface
```

Comment: how can do this in overriding?any help?